# Can you use RETURN AS within the @cypher Directive in your GraphQL Schema?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher

Say I have this simple schema with just a Person type:

```
// schema.graphql

type Person {
    Name: String,
    Age: Int,
    parents: [Person!]! @relationship(type: "PARENT", direction: OUT)
}
```

And I want a query that gets me every person's name with grandparent's name, by traversing the "PARENT" relationship twice. In Cypher I would write something like this:

```
MATCH (child:Person)-[:PARENT]->[parent:Person]-[:PARENT]->(grandparent:Person)
RETURN child.Name AS child_name, grandparent.Name AS grandparent_name
```

Is it possible to use this cypher query within a `@cypher` directive for my graphQL query? The goal is to do the "traversing" in cypher to get the grandparent's name and return it directly with the child's name, instead of having to traverse through the GraphQL response to get it, which I would need to do if I just returned the child.

My idea was to define a new type for what this query would return, something like:

```
// schema.graphql

type Child_Grandparent_Pair{
    child_name: String,
    grandparent_name: String
}
```

And write my GraphQL query like so:

```
// schema.graphql

type Query{
    getChildrenAndGrandparentsNames:[Child_Grandparent_Pair]
    @cypher(
        statement: "MATCH (child:Person)-[:PARENT]->[parent:Person]-[:PARENT]->                    
    (grandparent:Person)
        RETURN child.Name AS child_name, grandparent.Name AS grandparent_name"
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. When I try to query on my new query type, I get an error from neo4j that the return type isn't defined. Hopefully this makes sense what I'm trying to do. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a Object/Map that matches the shape of your GraphQL type:

```
type Query {
    getChildrenAndGrandparentsNames: [Child_Grandparent_Pair]
        @cypher(
            statement: """
             MATCH (child:Person)-[:PARENT]->[parent:Person]-[:PARENT]->(grandparent:Person)
-            RETURN child.Name AS child_name, grandparent.Name AS grandparent_name
+            RETURN { child_name: child.name, grandparent_name: grandparent.name }
            """
        )
}
```